# Multiple comparators without operator< (C++)

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue

I have a class `bit` that I want to sort by different criteria for different priority queues.

In `bit.h` I have:

```
#include<vector>
#include<queue>

class bit {
  static std::priority_queue<bit, std::deque<bit>> bigBitVector;
  mutable long long startTime;
  mutable long long endTime;
  // other methods, constructor, etc.
  static bool startTimeComp(const bit &a, const bit &c) {
    return a.startTime > c.startTime;
  }
  static bool endTimeComp(const bit &a, const bit &c) {
    return a.endTime > c.endTime;
  }
}
```

In another file I try to initialize one priority queue of `bit` objects as:

```
std::priority_queue<bit, std::deque<bit>, decltype(&bit::startTimeComp)> bigBitVector(bit::startTimeComp);
```

and another as

```
std::priority_queue<bit, std::deque<bit>, decltype(&bit::endTimeComp)> bitQueue(bit::endTimeComp);
```

but I get an error:

> /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_function.h:386:20:  error: no match for ‘operator<’ (operand types are ‘const bit’ and ‘const bit’)

I checked for this error and I found others with the problem, where they wanted to define something like

```
bool operator<(const bit &a) const {...}
```

and the error occurs because the `const` is missing. But if I add `const` to my comparators, the compiler complains because a function can't be both `static` and `const`; if I remove `static`, it complains because it can't be accessed without a specific object.

It seems like the issue is that the priority queue is looking for a specific `<` operator, rather than taking the comparator that I've provided. I don't want to provide a `<` operator because then I can't have two different priority queues sort the same data in two different ways.

Is there any way I can define multiple comparators and avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the comparator on the static member

```
static std::priority_queue<bit, std::deque<bit>> bigBitVector;
```

By default it will use `std::less` as comparator, which in turn compares elements with `operator<` which `bit` does not overload. Either overloading `operator<` for `bit` or specifying another comparator for `bigBitVector` should solve your issue.

Comment: When I try to use `startTimeComp` as the comparator for the static member, it tells me "Incomplete type 'bit' is used in nested name specifier'. Is there any way to define the bit class to have a queue that references a method of the bit class?

Comment: I don't think this will work. You cant use a class before it's fully declared. You can make the comparator functions free functions. Or you make `bigBitVector` a singleton instead of a static member.